# android virtual keyboard remove white space button

Tags: android, keyboard

I want to stop user from entering white space into the edittext, easiest way is to do not have button in keyboard appearing on click.

how to hide white space button from keyboard ?

or is there any other way to stop user entering white space into the edit text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

following link solved the issue

http://thedevelopersinfo.com/2009/11/15/filtering-data-in-edittext-component-in-android/

Answer (score 2):

The best way would be to do it programatically... the only thing you have to do is setting a [listener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/method/KeyListener.html) to the EditText and remove all the "spaces" while the user is writing. I think this is the best choice because there are some handsets that have a real keyboard that you can't obviously modify.